# Updating Div on Parent Page, preferably by use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used jQuery's .html() function to update content before, but it has always been inside an .ajax() function, for example:

```
$.ajax({
       padding : 15,
       type    : "POST",
       cache   : false,
       url     : "anyPage.php?page=ajax",
       data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
       success: function(data) {
        $("#Div").html(data);   
       }
      });
```

Problem is, in order to utilize TinyMCE, I had to open it in Fancybox inside of an iframe, but I ran into the problem of Posting data, which was solved by submitting the form to a PHP $_GET URL (pretty sure that's not what it's actually called), and then closing Fancybox:

```
<? if($_GET['page'] == "X"){
$_SESSION["X"] = $_POST['X']; 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>';
die();} ?>
```

That successfully passes the Post variable into a Session variable, which I can then call from inside the main page. Problem is, I'd like to also refresh a div on the main page, and am encountering problems.

I don't think I can use .ajax(), at least I haven't had any luck with trying to use it.

I've also tried using different combinations of .html() and .load() with .parent() and whatnot. A couple examples of things I've tried (the others have been long since overwritten):

```
parent.document.getElementById("Div").innerHTML = "something";
```

and

```
parent.$("Div").html("Some updated text");
```

Inserted both as follows:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$("Div").html("Some updated text");
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>';
```

Haven't found anything that will work. Wondering if anyone can lend me some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domains match, in the iframe and the parent document you should be able to access the parent using either of the following:

```
window.parent
parent
top          // If the parent is the top-level document
window.top
```

Since `parent` and `top` can be overwritten by javascript I would go with `window.parent` or `window.top`

Comment: After a little fiddling, I came up with `echo "<script  type=\"text/javascript\">$('#nav', window.parent.document).html(\"<p>Test</p>\"); parent.$.fancybox.close();</script>";` which worked. Thanks.